# How to pass JSON data (list created using Jquery) to an action in controller in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a function in jquery which creates a list of values being selected from a checkbox. Now I want to have this list in my controller action. I have converted this list to JSON but I am not able to pass it to the controller. I also tried creating a custom model corresponding to the json data.

### Jquery Code

```
$("button").click(function () {
             //alert("clicked");
             var obj = {};
             //var tempRadio = [];
             for (var i = 1; i <= globalVar; i++) {
                 if ($("#" + i).prop("checked") == true) {
                     obj[i] = $('input[class=' + i + ']:checked').val();


                 }
             }

             $.ajax({

                     contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                     dataType: 'json',
                     type: 'POST',
                     url: '@Url.Action("SkillAdd","User")',
                     data: JSON.stringify(obj),
                     //data:  hello,

                     error:function ()
                     {
                         alert("Error");
                     }, 
                     success: function () {
                         alert(JSON.stringify(obj));
                     }
                 });




         });
```

### Controller Code

```
public ActionResult SkillAdd(List<string> Id, List<string> Name)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

### Controller Code with Custom Model

```
public ActionResult SkillAdd(List<MyModel> object)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an object in javascript but you need to create an array so that it can be mapped to `List` at post. So change your js code to be :

```
var obj = [];  // it's array now
```

and then you will add items in it like in your loop:

```
obj.push( $('input[class=' + i + ']:checked').val());
```

and in your ajax call name the parameter what you have in your controller action:

```
data:{ Id : obj }
```

and now you can have a parameter in action method `List<string>` which would hold the data posted by ajax call.

```
public ActionResult SkillAdd(List<string> Id)
{
    return View();
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: "var obj = [];" I did it already. Dont we have to stringyfy the array? Also its not working.

Comment: you can try `stringify` if it is not working, but you need array not object

Comment: @Ehsan_Sajjad ya i declared the obj as array itself. Is it necessary to add values to array using push ?